# Showing a function is continuously differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f=\begin{cases} 0 , \mbox{if x=(0,0)}\\ \frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}\ \mbox{otherwise}\end{cases}$

Let $\gamma$ be a differentiable mapping from $\Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R}^2$ with $\gamma(0)=(0,0)$ and $|\gamma'(0)|>0$ . Let $g(t)=f(\gamma(t))$, Show that if $\gamma \in C^1$ then $g\in C^1$.

I am stuck at proving the continuity of the derivative at $t=0$ any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easily seen that $f$ is $C^\infty$ on the open set $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{0,0\}$. So by composition, the function $g$ is $C^1$ on the open set $\{t\;;\;\gamma(t)\neq(0,0)\}$. By the chain rule, we find
$$
g'(t)=\frac{x(t)^2(x(t)^2+3y(t)^2)}{(x(t)^2+y(t)^2}x'(t)-\frac{2x(t)^3y(t)}{(x(t)^2+y(t)^2)^2}y'(t).
$$

Now at $0$. It is easily seen that $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$, so $g$ is continuous at $0$. By assumption on $\gamma'(0)$, $0$ is isolated in $\{t\;;\;\gamma(t)=(0,0)\}$. To prove that $g$ is differentiable at $0$, it suffices to show that $\lim_0g'(t)$ exists. Then the derivative at $0$ is this limit, and the derivative is automatically continuous at $0$. That's an easy consequence of the mean value theorem.

By assumption on $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, we have $\gamma'(0)=(\alpha,\beta)\neq(0,0)$. Note that 
$$
x(t)=\alpha t+t\epsilon(t)\qquad\mbox{and}\qquad y(t)=\beta t+t\delta(t)
$$
with $\lim_0\epsilon(t)=\lim_0\delta(t)=0$.

Now substituting these in the formula for $g'(t)$, we find after simplification:
$$
g'(t)=\frac{(\alpha+\epsilon(t))^2((\alpha+\epsilon(t))^2+3(\beta+\delta(t))^2)}{((\alpha+\epsilon(t))^2+(\beta+\delta(t))^2)^2}x'(t)-\frac{2(\alpha+\epsilon(t))^3(\beta+\delta(t))}{((\alpha+\epsilon(t))^2+(\beta+\delta(t))^2)^2}y'(t).
$$
When $t$ tends to $0$, this converges, after simplification, to
$$
g'(0)=\frac{\alpha^3}{\alpha^2+\beta^2}.
$$

So $g$ is continuously differentiable at $0$.

Note that without further assumptions, you don't know if $g$ is differentiable at other $t$'s such that $\gamma(t)=(0,0)$.